# Why isn't this working? (a.getNumer() and this.getNumer() are returning the same value)

Tags: java

Hey I'm in a cs class and I was recently given a small lab that for the most part is pretty simple.  But the last part is messing me up, my code is:

```
    public Rational add(Rational a) {
            Rational addRational = new Rational(a.getNumer() * this.getDenom() + this.getNumer() * a.getDenom(), a.getDenom() * this.getDenom());
            return addRational;
    }
```

For some reason, a.getNumer() and this.getNumer() is returning the same number, (as is a.getDenom() and this.getDenom()).  What should I fix, and why is it breaking?

Just in case it helps, here's the part of the test thats saying it is failing:

```
    @Test
    public void testL6Add() {
    Random rnd = new Random(7);

    Rational rationalValueA;
    Rational rationalValueB;
    Rational rationalAnswer;

    int v1, v2, v3, v4;
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            v1 = rnd.nextInt(500);
            v2 = rnd.nextInt(500);
            v3 = rnd.nextInt(500);
            v4 = rnd.nextInt(500);
            rationalValueA = new Rational(v1, v2);
            rationalValueB = new Rational(v3, v4);
            rationalAnswer = rationalValueA.add(rationalValueB);
            assertEquals("Trying " + rationalValueA + " plus " + rationalValueB,
                    v1*v4 + v2*v3, rationalAnswer.getNumer());
            assertEquals("Trying " + rationalValueA + " plus " + rationalValueB,
                    v2 * v4, rationalAnswer.getDenom());
   }
```

I know (or at least think) that the problem is a.getNumer() is returning the same value as this.getNumer() because I made it output (using System.out.print) each value and in the test v1 and v2 are being created but when it's doing rational1.addRationa(rational2), it's just adding rational2 to itself

Comment: Post your code here, not at pastebin.

Comment: Post how you create instances of Rational class and call add method.

Comment: Is there any reason that it should not?

Comment: @cagirici shouldn't this.getNumer() get me rationalValueA.getNumer() isntead of rationalValueB.getNumer()?  if not, how do i get that?

Comment: There is no guarantee that random method would always return different value. That must be why sometimes you get this,getNumber and a.getNumber as the same

Comment: @neo I added System.out.println("v1: " + v1); and so forth for v1-v4 and then System.out.println("this.getNum: " + this.getNumer()); and so forth for this and a and numer and denom for each at the appropriate places and it showed that v1 != v3 and v2 != v4

Comment: are the fields numer and denom in the Rational class declared static?

Comment: @Henry  yes, should they not be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields `numer` and `denom` in the `Rational` class were declared static. This means the same memory location is used for all instances of the class. The second instance has therefore overwritten the values of the first instance.